# Convert HTML Forms to ASP.NET forms with a silent post and response handler

Tags: asp.net, html, parsing, dotnetnuke, webrequest

I want to write a DotNetNuke module that can take an HTML form and parse or transform it into an asp.net form that would then do a HTTPPost to the page specified in the HTML Form's action property.

We regularly run into the need to use pre-existing forms (from existing sites and Service Providers like Paypal and Constant Contact). Currently, we either use an IFrame, manually convert the form into an ASP.NET user control, or use a forms module to recreate the form. It seems like it should be fairly easy to create an automated way to handle these with ASP.NET.

My quick plan:
1.) Admin Users will paste the form into a settings page and then click a convert button
2.) The code will parse the HTML and generate a ascx User Control from it and store the posting address. We may just have to add runat="server" into each of the form controls
3.) The admin user will be able to specify a variety of response codes and corresponding messages. (i.e. 1 -> "Thank you for your Donation", 2-> "We were not able to process your request at this time due to ...")

Users would then fill out the form and hit submit. The system would get the names and values of all form controls and Silent Post that to the posting address and get the response code and then display the corresponding message.

Any thoughts or suggestions of the best way to do this? Are there any tools that already do this or would be helpful?

Thanks,
David O'Leary

Comment: i did a little something like this some time ago - basically you simply use js to submit a form object - is that like what you are trying to do? http://forums.asp.net/post/857770.aspx

Comment: heres an old old thread about this that I was involved with - http://forums.asp.net/t/873823.aspx/2/10?Submitting+a+form+to+an+external+site+using+DNN